# Skip job in a multi-config job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to know if there is a way or a plugin to skip a specific job from within multi-config job.

So let's assume that I have an array of 2 platforms by 2 OSes:

```
O | O
------
O | O
```

and usually all of them will run.

However, I would like to provide a parameter to the multi-config job so that I can skip one of them and only run the others :

```
O | X
------
O | O
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add axis, you can check "Filter combinaisons" in which you can add regular expression to skip or not test. Example :

```
!(label=="linux" && compiler=="cc")
```

Block test with params linux and cc.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. The only issue is that I asked it poorly. :) I would have liked to know if there is way of programmatically skip it. Basically, I would like to run all of them most of the time, but sometimes just skip one by passing a parameter when pressing "Build now". Is this possible?

Comment: Don't know if it works, but you can add a parameter to the job, named EXCLUDE for example, and then use $EXCLUDE on the filter combinaisons. To avoid errors during input, I would prefer a "Choice parameter" with all you need.

Comment: Sounds like a decent solution, but I wasn't sure if variables work inside of the filter combinations field (except for the ones defining the axes). The ideal solution would have been some way of deciding to skip a test in the "Execute shell" area, but I didn't find any script which could do it.